# Can I ignore or suppress warnings in JDBC for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1364

I have an `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement that executes fine (but with warnings) in the `mysql>` prompt:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
Warning (Code 1364): Field 'x' doesn't have a default value
```

However, when I try to execute the same statement via JDBC the warning shows up as an `SQLException` and no rows are updated:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'x' doesn't have a default value
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)  
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2086)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1365)
```

**Is there a JDBC or mysql connector setting or command to ignore or suppress these warnings?**

I'm using MySQL Community Server 5.1.31 with MySQL connector 5.1.8 and Java 1.5.0_24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to suppress these completely.

Comment: (: That works. Interesting, I thought I had tried that.. Thanks!

Comment: The `IGNORE` clause doesn't suppress the warning per se - it merely suppresses the source of the warning. So this is not a general solution for the actual problem. I'm disappointed that MySQL JDBC driver designers didn't use `SQLWarning` as it was intended to be used.